# Websocket handshake manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, tcp, websocket, handshake

In order to create a websocket connection in javascript we can use the websocket api for example:

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

then the browser will initiate an handshake via http get request with those headers:

```
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
```

and the server response :

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
```

after that the client and server will have websocket connection opened.

So my question is if it's possible to do the handshake on other methods ? and if it's possible to take care of the handshake via javascript like xhr or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The WebSockets handshake is only defined with GET, see [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). Also, since WebSockets do not fit into the request-response scheme of HTTP but essentially build a permanent connection where both server and client can write independently from each other there is no way to deal with WebSockets using XHR which expects a single response to a single request.

Comment: I can't hook that get request and fake a response via javascript?
i would like the websocket to start the connection without the handshake and any protocol violation can be dealt with on the server side

Comment: @avidahan: there is no "no handshake" with websockets. What you essentially would need is access to plain TCP sockets and then you could do your own protocol. But this would have nothing to do with WebSockets, i.e. WebSockets are not plain TCP sockets but only look a lot like this from outside.

Comment: @avidahan what are you REALLY trying to accomplish? It sounds like you are trying to abuse WebSockets for something they are not intended for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If using websocket without a proper handshake called abusing than yes I am trying to abuse it, it seems do that it’s not possible

Comment: @avidahan but WHY do you want this? What is your GOAL?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don’t have a specific goal just an idea for a project that’s all

Comment: @avidahan well, if we knew what your idea is, we could tell you if it is feisible or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  That’s my idea , I would like to create a websocket connection without an handshake and code a server that can establish the connection and deal with the protocol violation

Comment: @avidahan: Then your idea is not feasible. I recommend to come up with another project which does not require features which don't exist.

Comment: Websocket is a well defined protocol, which part of is the initial HTTP-based handshake. If you take the handshake out, you can no longer call it a websocket.